# How can we get all usernames list only not user objects with django ORM

Tags: sql, django, database, orm

I want to know that how can we get list of required field data from django models. In my case i want to get all usernames from users models.

```
receivers = User.objects.all()
```

this return all users objects. I want to get usernames directly. Something like below:

```
receivers = User.objects.all(username)
output:
["ahmed","dummy","hamza","sentence"]
```

in sql query looks like below:

```
SELECT username from USER
```

Comment: [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
receivers=User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True)
```

Try this code, you can read more about this in django offical documents

Answer (score 1):

```
receivers = User.objects.all().values_list('username')
```

It will return list of all usernames.